# Async React-select with redux

Tags: redux, react-select

I am trying to make an async react-select component with redux but somehow not able to get search results in the dropdown. Very new to this. Please help :)

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Select from 'react-select';

import { fetchInstitutionsIfNeeded } from '../../actions/institutions';

class Signup extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: null
        };
        this.getInstitutions = this.getInstitutions.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    onChange(input) {
        this.setState({
            value: input
        });
    }

    getInstitutions(input) {
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        if (!input) {
            return Promise.resolve({ options: [] });
        }
        dispatch(fetchInstitutionsIfNeeded(input));
    }

    render() {
        let options = this.props.options;
        return (
            <div>
                <Select.Async
                    name="institute"
                    value={this.state.value}
                    autoload={false}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    loadOptions={this.getInstitutions}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    options: state.institutions.options
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Signup);
```

Also options object is also properly formatted and is getting updated properly in redux store but not reflecting back in select async's dropdown.

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072867/use-async-react-select-with-redux-saga, should be useful.

Comment: You'll need to read from your redux store state.  In the above you are just dispatching an action with nothing returned.

Comment: I have worked a lot with react-select using redux, but, I don't understand exactly what is your problem, could you explain more about your problem?!

Answer (score 6):

Try this, we can also return from action but it breaks the whole idea of reducers.

```js
// actions.js
export const getProducts = (input = '') => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: GET_PRODUCTS_PENDING,
    payload: {},
  });
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`/api/v1/products/`);
    dispatch({
      type: GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
      payload: response.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    // handle errors
  }
};

// components.jsx
class Signup extends PureComponent {
  async getProductsForSelect(input) {
    await this.props.getProducts(input);
    return this.props.product.options;
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

        <AsyncSelect
          isMulti
          cacheOptions
          defaultOptions
          loadOptions={(e) => this.getProductsForSelect(e)}
        />

      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.