# How to use redux-saga instead of using fetch on the Select component?

Tags: react-select

From my previous project I had learned that any side effects is best handled by redux-saga. A connected component would subscribe to the state and any actions triggered would dispatch an action. A redux-saga would listen to a particular action and fire off a request to the backend for some data, and on success the saga would fire off a success action and update the state with the requested data.

In [this](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/examples/src/components/GithubUsers.js) example of react-select, it is using fetch.js to make a call to get the git hub users. I noticed that if you typed too quickly the API would reject your requests. This brings me back to redux-saga because of takeLatest cancels the previous request so it would be nice to use redux-saga to manage the asynchronous calls.

I was wondering if this could be achieved with redux-saga. The reason I ask is because the loadOptions of the Select component takes a function that returns a promise. And my saga is only dispatching actions and updating the redux state, and not returning a promise back to the loadOptions prop.

Appreciate any advices on this...

To put this into perspective, this is a cut down version of my code:

**Forms:**

```
loadOptions = (input) => {
   this.props.dispatch({type: 'GET_USERS', input});
}

<Form model="test">
   <Control model='.field1' component={Async} loadOptions={(input) => this.loadOptions(input)/>
</Form>
```

**reducer:**

```
case 'GET_USERS':
   return state.set('input', action.input);
case 'USERS_LOADED':
   return state.set('options', action.data.items);
```

**Saga:**

```
export default getUsers*() {
   const input = yield select((state) => state.get('input'));
   const requestUrl = `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${input}`;

   try {
      const response = yield call(axios.get, requestUrl);
      yield put({type: 'USERS_LOADED', response);
   } catch (err) {
      yield put(loadUsersError(err));
   }
}

export default rootSaga*() {
   takeLatest('GET_USERS', getUsers);
}
```

Comment: I have the same question. I think we should not use `Async` component, but `Select` with `searchable` prop. On input change `loadOptions` action should be dispatched, and options from the redux store should be passed to `Select` through `options` prop. You can create your HOC implements this logic.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your example so I can mark it as an answer?

Comment: I found a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072867/use-async-react-select-with-redux-saga?rq=1) and this solved my problem.

Comment: Cool, it is what I meant.